# The way that a regular expression describes a regular language

Tags: computer-science, formal-systems

A formal language is a set of words in some alphabet. It may be defined as being generated by a formal grammar or as being recognized by an automaton. For a regular language, it can also be described by a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Definition).

1. A regular expression is not an automaton. I wonder if it is
   considered as a [formal grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar#Formal_definition)?
2. Do other non-regular languages, such as context-free languages and
   recursively enumerable languages, have counterparts of regular
   expressions?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: I don't understand "For a regular expression, it can also be described by a regular expression." -- could you rephrase that?

Comment: @joriki: Thanks for pointing it out. I intended to mean "For a regular <del> expression </del> **language**, it can also be described by a regular expression."

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your definitions. The set of palindromes on a 2-symbol alphabet - is that a formal language? It can't be recognized by a finite state automaton, nor described by a regular expression, if I remember right.

Comment: @Gerry: My questions are two: (1) Is regular expression some kind of formal grammar? Or at least very close related in the sense that one can be derived trivially from the other? (2) For other non-regular languages which can have formal grammars, is it possible that they can be described by some generalized versions of regular expression? Note that I know they cannot be described by regular expression, or else they would have been regular languages.

Comment: Thanks, Tim. I'm out of my depth here, as I don't know what "formal grammar" means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Firstly, I would like to point out that regular expressions are equivalent to finite state machines. Secondly, I would certainly say that regular expressions are (at least have a way to transform into) formal grammars. Regular languages are a subset of context-free languages, which are a subset of context-sensitive grammars. Wikipedia's description of a formal grammar certainly fits with one of the usual notations for context-free languages. Also, to systematically transform a regular expression into a formal grammar, take $a$ as any plain character in the following transformation:

   $$T(PQ) = S_m \rightarrow T(P)\hbox{ ending at state }n - 1, S_n \rightarrow T(Q)$$
   $$T(P|Q) = S_n \rightarrow T(P), S_n \rightarrow T(Q)$$
   $$T(P^*) = S_n \rightarrow \epsilon, S_n \rightarrow T(PP^*)$$
2. Due to the fact that there have been many extensions to regular expressions, such as backreferences, and these cover a larger class of grammars, I would assume so. However, for those classes specifically, I don't know whether there are other regular expression like ways of representing them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes to everything, and more.

Let's clarify a few things, first; because the various terms apply **far** more broadly than is generally recognized - even in the literature (that is: the literature pre-dating the 21st century, or "classical" literature).

**Languages, Translations, etc.**
First, a language is classically defined as a set of words drawn from an alphabet $X$. The words, themselves, are sequences of elements taken from $X$ and, in all, comprise a set that is denoted $X^*$. Included in this is the empty word, traditionally denoted $λ$ or $ε$, but which I'll just designate as "1". An operation exists that combines two words by joining them up one after the other: concatenation, and it is denoted by juxtaposing the words themselves. Thus, if $X = \{a,b\}$ and $a, b ∈ X$, then (first) $a, b ∈ X^*$, as well (words of length one) and (second) $aa, ab, ba, bb ∈ X^*$ (words of length two). The concatenation of $ab$ and $ba$ is, then, just $abba$ - a word of length 4.

**Monoids**
This endows $X^*$ with the structure of an algebra that has a product operation (concatenation) and an identity (the empty word) that satisfy the equations:
$$(uv)w = u(vw),\quad w1 = w = 1w\quad (u, v, w ∈ X^*).$$
Such a algebra is called a [Monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid).

An algebraic structure of a given kind generated from a set $X$ that has no relations other than those derivable by the axioms for the algebra is called a *free algebra*, and particularly: one that is *freely generated* from the set $X$. The word algebra $X^*$ is the free monoid generated from $X$.

Classically, formal language theory is (almost exclusively) focused on free monoids. There are two notable exceptions: (1) [Parikh's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parikh%27s_theorem), where you have commutativity $uv = vu$ imposed, and (2) Translations, which generalize the "language" concept by having both an input alphabet $X$ and output alphabet $Y$.

For translations, the corresponding set is $X^* × Y^*$ - the set of all ordered pairs of words taken from $X$ and $Y$, each pair $(u,v) ∈ X^* × Y^*$ giving you a translation pair (in which $v$ is treated as a translation of $u$). This is a monoid in its own right. Its identity is $(1_X, 1_Y)$, formed from the respective identities $1_X ∈ X^*$ and $1_Y ∈ Y^*$. The product is given by $(u,v)(u',v') = (uu',vv')$, where $u, u' ∈ X^*$ and $v, v' ∈ Y^*$.

Provided that $X^*$ and $Y^*$ are non-overlapping sets ($X^* ∩ Y^* = ∅$), this can be *equivalently* described as the free monoid $(X ∪ Y)^*$ subject to the additional axiom $xy = yx$, for $x ∈ X$ and $y ∈ Y$. So, a "translation" is like a language except it has two (mutually commuting) channels instead of just one. Both $X^*$ and $Y^*$ can be treated as already being included in $X^* × Y^*$ as subalgebras by the mappings
$$u ∈ X^* ↦ (u,1_Y) ∈ X^* × Y^*,\quad v ∈ Y^* ↦ (1_X,v) ∈ X^* × Y^*.$$
It is through this inclusion that you get the commutativity property:
$$(u,1_Y)(1_X,v) = (u,v) = (1_X,v)(u,1_Y),\quad (u ∈ X^*,\quad v ∈ Y^*).$$

Of course, that can be generalized further: $X^* × Y^* × Z^*$ for three (mutually commuting) channels, for instance; or to any number of channels. In the extreme case, you have something like $\{a\}^* × \{b\}^* × ⋯ × \{z\}^*$, which is equivalent to the free monoid $X^*$ over $X = \{a, b, ⋯, z\}$ subject to commutativity $uv = vu$ - the case where Parikh's Theorem lives.

**Language/Translations Families As Families Of Monoid Subsets**
The "regular expression" concept applies *generally* to all monoids. The corresponding subsets are called "rational" and the term "regular" is usually just reserved to the case where the monoid is free. Similar consideration applies to other language families.

This is done as follows. Subsets of monoids also form an algebra that contains the structure of a monoid. If $M$ is a monoid, then the subsets together comprise $M$ - the "power set" of $M$. Its identity is $\{1\} ∈ M$, where $1 ∈ M$ is the identity of $M$. Its product is $AB = \{ab ∈ M: a ∈ A, b ∈ B\}$, where $A, B ⊆ M$. The monoid $M$, itself, is injected into $M$ by $m ∈ M ↦ \{m\} ∈ M$ as the corresponding singleton sets. So, $M$ is contained in $M$ as a subalgebra, and it is out of this that the convention of treating $m$ and $\{m\}$ synonymously arises.

Different sub-families of $M$ lead to different language families when $M$ is a free monoid $M = X^*$. They **also** lead to a parallel set of *translation* families in the case $M = X^* × Y^*$. Corresponding to the regular languages over $X$ are the rational transductions between $X$ and $Y$. Corresponding to the context-free languages over $X$ are the push-down transductions between $X$ and $Y$. This is equivalently described in terms of "simple syntax directed translations". Likewise, corresponding to the recursively enumerable languages over $X$ are the recursively enumerable translations between $X$ and $Y$.

**The Singleton Family & Partially Ordered Monoids**
The simplest family are the "single element" subsets $ℑM = \{\{m\}: m ∈ M\}$. For $X$, the corresponding set $ℑX^*$ is the family of one word languages. This endows $ℑM$ with the same structure, algebraically, as $M$, but also with an additional item - a partial ordering relation $A ≤ B$ given by the subset relation $A ⊆ B$. Over $ℑM$ the relation is trivial: $A ≤ B ⇔ A = B$, but that won't be the case for the other subset families.

**The Finite Subset Family & Idempotent Semirings/Dioids**
The simplest family where we also have the "+" operation of regular expressions is the finite subsets $M$ of $M$. It contains a "+" operation that is given by the subset union $A + B = A ∪ B$, an identity "0", which is just the empty set $0 = ∅$, and the subset ordering relation. The "+" and "0" operations may be defined in terms of the $≤$ relation in terms of the "least upper bound" relation "sup" as:
$$A + B = \sup \{A,B\},\quad 0 = \sup ∅.$$

Therefore, the "expressions" of $M$ form an algebraic structure that can be described as a partially ordered monoid that is closed under finite least upper bounds, and distributive with respect to it:
$$\sup \{pAq\} = p (\sup \{A\}) q.$$
This captures the algebraic properties
$$p0q = 0,\quad p(u + v)q = puq + pvq.$$
The least upper bound properties are captured, algebraically, by the identities:
$$u + 0 = u = 0 + u,\quad u + (v + w) = (u + v) + w,\quad u + v = v + u,\quad u + u = u.$$

In totality, that defines a [semiring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiring) that has the idempotency property $u + u = u$; i.e. an "idempotent semiring", or sometimes also known as a "dioid".

The corresponding expressions in $M$ are just polynomials ... with the understanding that all the coefficients are "1" since $2x = x + x = x$, $3x = x + x + x = x$, etc. in dioids.

Semirings differ from [rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)) in that they have no built-in "-" operation. So there are no negative coefficients, either.

**The Rational Subsets & Regular Expressions & Rational Transductions & Kleene Algebras**
The next simplest family adds in the "*" operator for regular expressions. They comprise the family $ℜM$ of the "rational subsets" of $M$. For a single alphabet $X$, $ℜX^*$ are the regular languages over $X$, while for two alphabets $ℜ(X^* × Y^*)$ are the rational transductions between $X$ and $Y$. The extra operation is given by:
$$A^* = {1} ∪ A ∪ A A ∪ A A A ∪ ⋯ = ⋃_{n≥0} A^n$$
where $A^0 = {1}$, $A^1 = A$, $A^2 = A A$, $A^3 = A A A$, etc.

Thus, $ℜM ⊆ M$ is the smallest family of subsets containing $ℑM$ closed under "+" and "*". These are the rational subsets of $M$. Their expressions are generically called rational expressions. In the case of free monoids $M = X^*$ the expressions for $ℜX^*$ are called regular expressions, while those of $ℜ(X^* × Y^*)$ are rational transductions.

The corresponding type of algebra, denoted here $D$, has all the operations and properties of a dioid, and is closed under the suprema of its rational subsets with distributivity holding for them:
$$A ∈ ℜD ⇒ \sup A ∈ D,\quad p(\sup A)q = \sup (pAq)\quad (p,q ∈ D,\quad A ∈ ℜD).$$
This can be captured by the additional axioms
$$\sup_{n≥0} (p u^n q) = p u^* q\quad (p,u,q ∈ D).$$

That gives you an axiomatization for regular expressions that also applies to rational transductions. Thus, provided that $X^*$ and $Y^*$ are non-overlapping, then $ℜ(X^* × Y^*)$ can be described as just regular expressions $ℜ(X ∪ Y)^*$, subject to the relations $xy = yx$, for $x ∈ X$ and $y ∈ Y$.

The algebra $ℜX^*$ is freely generated from $X$, while $ℜ(X^* × Y^*)$ is not free, but is subject to the relations just described. More generally, however, $ℜM$ is the free extension of the monoid $M$ to an algebra of this type. So, $ℜ(X^* × Y^*)$ can still be regarded as a free extension of the monoid $X^* × Y^*$.

A weaker axiom set also exists that fully captures the regular expression algebras $ℜX^*$. It asserts that the least solutions to the following fixed-point inequations
$$x ≥ a + bx,\quad x ≥ a + xc,$$
are respectively $b^* a$ and $a c^*$; or ... using the μ notation
$$μx·(a + bx) = b^* a,\quad μx·(a + xc) = a c^*.$$
When combined with the axioms of a dioid, this is enough to prove all the equations between regular expressions ... notwithstanding Conway's result from the 1960's that no finite set of equational identities fully captures the algebra of regular expressions.

With respect to the weaker axiom set, $ℜX^*$ is still free. In general, however, the axioms are too weak to prove, in general, that $ℜM$ is the free extension of a monoid $M$.

Both algebraic structures are called [Kleene Algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_algebra). The stronger axiom set define "*-continuous" (and "*-complete") Kleene algebras.

**Grammars For Arbitrary Monoids & Free Extensions**
Grammars can be defined for arbitrary monoids $M$, not just the free monoids $X^*$. In the classical case, the definition requires adding in an extra set $Q$ of variables such that $X^*$ and $Q^*$ are non-overlapping. They're usually called "non-terminals" in that context, while the elements of $X$ are then called "terminals". The corresponding set $(X ∪ Q)^*$ can be equivalently describe as the result $M[Q]$ of free extending the monoid $M = X^*$ with a set $Q$ of additional elements.

In general, an algebraic structure is freely extended by adding extra objects to it, and imposing no relations on this other than what can be derived from the axioms.

A grammar can then be defined by a set $H ⊆ M[Q] × M[Q]$, each item $(u,v) ∈ H$ of which gives you a phrase structure rule $u → v$, and by a "starting word" $S ∈ M[Q]$. The extra restriction $S ∈ Q$ almost always asserted in the classical literature is not necessary.

**Regular Grammars / One-Sided Affine Systems**
Grammars can be affine to the left or right, where all the rules are of the form $q → v$, with $v$ constant or linear over $Q$, with all the coefficients of $M$ either on the left or right. These correspond to regular grammars. For left-affine, the rules are of the forms $q → a$ and $q → q' c$, where $q, q' ∈ Q$ and $a, c ∈ M$, while for right-affine, they are of the forms $q → a$ and $q → b q'$, where $q, q' ∈ Q$ and $a, b ∈ M$.

The method for generating words generalizes to a method for generating elements of $M$, but is the same as described in the classical literature: you start with the word $S ∈ M[Q]$ and apply the phrase structure rules to the variables in the word repeatedly until you get an element of $M$.

Defining $[α] = { m ∈ M: α → m }$, for each $α ∈ M[Q]$, you can treat such grammars as fixed-point systems of inequations. Thus, for instance, if the grammar has $x,y ∈ M$, with $A, B ∈ Q$, and transitions $A → x B$, $B → 1$, $B → y A$, i.e. $H = \{(A, x B), (B, 1), (B, y A)\}$, then the corresponding system is
$$[A] ⊇ \{x\} [B],\quad B ⊇ \{1\} ∪ \{y\} A,$$
and corresponds to the following algebraic system
$$A ≥ x B,\quad B ≥ 1 + y A.$$
The least fixed point solution $μ(A,B)·(x B, 1 + y A)$ is then given by the regular expressions $(A, B) = (x (y x)^*, (y x)^*)$, so if the starting word is $S = x B y$, then the corresponding subset recognized by the grammar is $[S] = [x B y] = x (y x)^* y$.

All left-affine and right-affine systems can be solved, in this way, in Kleene algebra. This requires only the weaker axiom set, not *-continuity.

If the grammar is taken over the monoid $M = X^*$, then it gives you the classical notion of a regular grammar over an alphabet $X$.

If the grammar is taken over the monoid $M = X^* × Y^*$, then it gives you the family of rational transductions over $X$ and $Y$.

**Context-Free Grammars / Algebraic Fixed-Point Systems**
If the rules are of the form $q → w$, where $q ∈ Q$ and $w ∈ M[Q]$, then this corresponds to context-free grammars ... except, here, it's generalized to arbitrary monoids $M$.

For all such grammars, the separability property holds $[uv] = [u][v]$, where $u, v ∈ M[Q]$. So, these grammars can also be treated as fixed point systems. For example, $A → w$ and $A → x A y$, with start word $A z$, $A ∈ Q$, $w, x, y, z ∈ M$ corresponds to $[A] ⊇ \{w\} ∪ \{x\} [A] \{y\}$, and to the fixed point system $A ≥ w + x A y$, with starting expression $A z$. The subset generated by the grammar is then the result of applying the least fixed point solution $μA·(w + x A y)$ to the starting expression $A z$.

The corresponding family of subsets of the monoid $M$ can then be defined as $ℭM$. This gives you $ℭX^*$: the context-free languages over $X$ and $ℭ(X^* × Y^*)$: the push-down transductions between $X$ and $Y$. More generally, you could call $ℭM$ the context-free subsets of $M$.

**Parikh's Theorem: Solving Fixed-Point Systems (Commutative Case)**
For this, only the weaker axiom set for Kleene algebras is required. In the non-commutative case, the stronger axiom set, with *-continuity, is needed and requires also going a little outside of and beyond Kleene algebras (but only a little). More on that later...

For commutative Kleene algebras, the *-operation behaves like an exponential, with $(A + B)^* = A^* B^*$ and $0^* = 1$. So, you can formally define a calculus over it, by setting $d(x^*)/dx = x^*$. An analogue of Taylor's Theorem then holds for arbitrary Kleene polynomials:
$$φ(x+h) = φ(x) + h φ'(x+h).$$

By "Kleene polynomial", I mean any algebraic expression formed from constant coefficients and variables using the sum, product and star operations. So, $φ(x) = a x + b x^* c$ is an example of a Kleene polynomial in $x$, where $a$, $b$ and $c$ are constant coefficients.

In addition, the following property holds for Kleene polynomials:
$$a^* φ(a^* b) = a^* φ(b).$$
Finally, all Kleene polynomials are monotonic:
$$a ≥ b ⇒ φ(a) ≥ φ(b),$$
which is generally true for all Kleene algebras, not just the commutative ones, since the Kleene operations (sum, product, star) are all order-preserving.

Thus, letting $a = φ(0)$ and $b = φ'(a)$, it follows that
$$φ(b^* a) = φ(0) + b^* a φ'(b^* a) = a + b^* a φ'(a) = (1 + b^* b) a = b^* a.$$
So, $x = b^* a$ is a solution to $x ≥ φ(x)$. Conversely, by Taylor's Theorem, if $x ≥ φ(x)$, then
$$x ≥ φ(x) = φ(0) + x φ'(x) = a + x φ'(x).$$
Therefore, $x ≥ a$, and by monotonicity, $φ'(x) ≥ φ'(a) = b$. Therefore,
$$x ≥ a + x b,$$
from which it follows that $x ≥ a b^* = b^* a$. So, $b^* a$ is the *least* fixed point of $φ(x)$:
$$μx·φ(x) = φ'(φ(0))^* φ(0).$$

This can be used to solve finite systems of fixed-point inequations one variable at a time.

For the non-commutative case, it's necessary to go outside of and beyond Kleene algebras ... to a certain degree. The non-commutative result, however, can still be stated in Kleene algebraic form - in terms of rational expressions over non-free Kleene algebras.

**The Algebra Of Context-Free Expressions**
The main property of the algebra is that the least fixed points $μx·φ(x)$ for *all* Kleene polynomials $φ(x)$ are defined in it. The algebraic structure can be axiomatized in one of two different ways: either as a dioid $D$ with the property that they be closed under least upper bounds of its context-free subsets with continuity and distributivity:
$$p (\sup A) q = \sup (p A q),\quad p, q ∈ D,\quad A ∈ ℭD$$
or as a dioid closed under least fixed points, with the μ-continuity property
$$\sup_{n≥0} p φ^n(0) q = p (μx·φ(x)) q,$$
for arbitrary Kleene polynomials, where
$$φ^0(x) = x$,\quad φ^1(x) = φ(x),\quad φ^2(x) = φ(φ(x)),\quad φ^3(x) = φ(φ(φ(x))),\quad ⋯.$$

Both sets of axioms are equivalent - which has been known since 2018 (post-dating the original query by several years).

The corresponding expressions are **context-free expressions**.

The algebras are called μ-continuous Chomsky algebras or just ℭ-dioids.

**Kleene-Algebraic Representations Of Context-Free Expressions**
A *-continuous Kleene algebra $K$ can be extended to a ℭ-dioid by attaching for new elements $Z = \{b,d,p,q\}$ to it, as $K[Z]$ and subjecting it to the relations:
$$
k z = z k\quad (k ∈ K,\quad z ∈ Z),\quad b d = 1 = p q,\quad b q = 0 = p d.
$$
Denoting the set of relations by $ρ$, this leads to a larger Kleene algebra $K[Z]/ρ$. The subalgebra consisting of all the elements that commute with $\{b,d,q,p\}$:
$$\{ y ∈ K[Z]/ρ: y z = z y (z ∈ Z) \}$$
is just the ℭ-extension of $K$, itself, which I'll denote $Q^ℭ_ℜK$. This is an algebra for context-free expressions. In particular,
$$Q^ℭ_ℜ ℜM = ℭM$$
for arbitrary monoids, and more specifically still:
$$Q^ℭ_ℜ ℜX^* = ℭX^*,\quad Q^ℭ_ℜ ℜ(X^* × Y^*) = ℭ(X^* × Y^*).$$

For the grammar given above ($A → w$ and $A → x A y$, with start word $A z$), the corresponding context-free expression would be $b (x p)^* w (q y)^* d z$.

The full algebra $K[Q]/ρ$ is larger than $Q^ℭ_ℜ K$, since not all of its elements commute with $Z$. But the general element of the algebra can be reduced to a normal form consisting of a sum of regular expressions over $Q^ℭ_ℜ K$ and $Z$, where all the $\{d,q\}$ are to the left of all the $\{b,p\}$. For instance,
$$(x p)^* w (q y)^* = q y (q y)^* A + A + A (x p)^* x p,\quad A = μa·(w + x a y).$$

**Compiling Context-Free Expressions: The Chomsky-Schützenberger Theorem**
A grammar can be *directly* compiled into a context-free expression in any number of different ways. This is, ultimately, a 21st century outgrowth and refinement of the early 1960's [Chomsky-Schützenberger Representation Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky%E2%80%93Sch%C3%BCtzenberger_representation_theorem), which was established in peer-reviewed literature in the last few years.

This applies to translation grammars, too (i.e. simple syntax directed translation grammars). For instance, a grammar that translates $e a e$ to $e e A$, $c e$ to $e C$, $r e s$ to $e$, $t$ to $T$ with start word $z e$ translated to $e Z$, with $Q = \{e\}$, $X = \{a, c, r, s, z\}$, $Y = \{A, C, T, Z\}$ may be given by
$$e → e a e A,\quad e → c e C,\quad e → r e s,\quad e → t T,\quad z e Z,$$
with the start word $z e Z$ listed last. Then the following would each serve as compilations of the grammar
$$
p_0 \hat{S} (\hat{H} + \hat{X} + \hat{Y})^* q_0,\\
\hat{X} = q_a a + q_c c + q_r r + q_s s + q_t t + q_z z,\quad \hat{Y} = q_A A + q_C C + q_T T + q_Z Z,\\
\hat{S} = p_Z p_e p_z,\quad \hat{H} = q_e (p_A p_e p_a p_e + p_C p_e p_c + p_s p_e p_r + p_T p_t),
$$
and
$$
p_0 (\hat{H} + \hat{X} + \hat{Y})^* \hat{S} q_0,\\
\hat{X} = a p_a + c p_c + r p_r + s p_s + t p_t + z p_z,\quad \hat{Y} = A p_A + C p_C + T p_T + Z p_Z,\\
\hat{S} = q_Z q_e q_z,\quad \hat{H} = (q_A q_e q_a q_e + q_C q_e q_c + q_s q_e q_r + q_T q_t) p_e.
$$

The $p$ and $q$ operators form a sub-algebra satisfying
$$p_i q_i = 1,\quad p_i q_j = 0\quad (i ≠ j),$$
that commutes with $X$ and $Y$. It can be implemented using $Z$, for instance, by taking $p_0 = b b b b$, $q_0 = d d d d$, and choosing the $p_i$'s from the 15 remaining length-4 combinations of $\{b,p\}$, and the $q_i$'s from the 15 remaining length-4 combinations of $\{d,q\}$ as the respective reversals of the $p_i$'s.

The two compilations correspond, respectively, to top-down and bottom-up parsing. With suitable encoding of the $p_i$ and $q_i$, an [G]LR(0) parser actually can be directly written as the bottom-up compilation. All the optimizations you'd like to do with the LR parser (including pre-compiling LALR(k) or even LR(k) look-aheads!) can be developed directly from the context-free expression, itself.

Another compilation - more suited to parsing applications - may be given by
$$z p_0 X (a p_3 X)^* q_0 Z,\quad X = (r p_1 + c p_2)^* t T (q_1 s + q_2 C + q_3 A)^*,$$
where the $p$'s and $q$'s are implemented in $Z$ by
$$
p_0 = b b,\quad p_1 = b p,\quad p_2 = p b,\quad p_3 = p p,\\
q_0 = d d,\quad q_1 = q d,\quad q_2 = d q,\quad q_3 = q q.
$$